# Using serverside HTML-templates with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling with Reactjs and component rendering.

Basically I've regular html-templates at the server and I'm trying to use them as a JSX-components with the React. Otherwise it works just fine, but I'm not able to fire the events for example: **this.handleSubmit.**

How to render the loaded template as a React-element?

```
//Template /index.html
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit"
</form>

//Template loader
var App = React.createClass({
    componentDidMount: function() {
         this.updateContent();
    },
    updateContent: function(){
        /**
         * Loads the template from the server and sets 
         * a new state
         */
        var url = this.props.source.slice(1);
        $.get(url, function(result) {
            var html = result;
            if (this.isMounted()) {
                this.setState({
                    content: html
                });
            }
        }.bind(this));
    },
    handleSubmit: function(){
        console.log('Submit fired');
    }
    render: function() {
        var converter = new HTMLtoJSX({createClass: false});
        var jsx = '/** @jsx React.DOM */ ' + converter.convert(this.state.content);
        return (
            <div>
                {JSXTransformer.exec(jsx)}
            </div>
     );
});

React.render(
  <App source="#/index.html" />,
  mountPoint
);
```

Comment: Why?  Include an example of one of these templates, please.

Comment: There's a sample of the template file in the very top of the code-section.

Answer (score 1):

JSX isn't templates for a **markup language**, it's a syntax extension to the JavaScript **programming language**.  The distinction is important here.

You need to convert JSX to JS (usually done when building your project).  If we modify your code to be valid JSX it looks like this:

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And when run through the jsx tools the output is the following JavaScript expression.

```
React.createElement("form", {onSubmit: this.handleSubmit}, 
    React.createElement("input", {type: "text"}), 
    React.createElement("input", {type: "submit"})
)
```

You need to execute this code in render, with the correct `this` context.  You could do this by wrapping the above in a function before serving it to the client:

```
function renderThingy(){
    React.createElement("form", {onSubmit: this.handleSubmit}, 
        React.createElement("input", {type: "text"}), 
        React.createElement("input", {type: "submit"})
    )
}
```

And calling that in render:

```
render: function() {
    return (
        <div>
            {renderThingy.call(this)}
        </div>
     );
}
```

This is of course confusing, and it's not apparent if handleSubmit is used by anything.  Then of course, there's the issue of loading code asynchronously... I'd rather not delve into that here.

This also severely limits what you can do in your 'template', and various other problems will pop up.

## tl;dr don't do this

---

If you want to use JSX on the server: cool, you just need a JS runtime, and a component.  `React.renderToString` or `React.renderToStaticMarkup` will take care of actually giving you valid html.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The reason why I'm using server side templates is that I'll get unified i18n-support + few extra things from my Django-framework.

The initial idea was to create those templates on the server, then render them to view as React-views, and finally fill up the necessary data.

So the templates are already ready on the server and I've gone trough of the JSX-converters, which may do the job on the fly, like: http://facebook.github.io/react/html-jsx.html

Comment: That's going to be very slow... the jsx compiler isn't very performant and requires a lot of code to run.  What about creating JSX components that are compiled to js and used as django templates?  e.g. `<div>{"{%trans something%}"}</div>`; or using django's [recommendation for translation in js](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code)

Answer (score 1):

The template should be precompiled using `React.renderToString()`, then the html returned from the function has all the extra DOM attributes such as data-react-id needed to make a reconciliation with the client.

This is because the `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` in your template **doesn't have the react data** associated, **react doesnt care/know about it**.

React can render clean html too without the bloat using React.renderToStaticMarkup() function;

Take a look here http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendertostring